# how to let Excel or notepad input numbers from floating number keypad in java

Tags: java, swing, keypad

I made a floating number keypad in java, it can key in figures in java application, but i doesn't work for other windows applications, such as Excel,notepad etc. So Anyone can help tell me how to let my number keypad  use in other windows applications also.

[image: my floating number keypad img:]

Comment: Java uses a container, which doesn't allow it to interact with the OS (I suppose typing into other programs is considered interacting with the OS), I'm not sure, but maybe JNI might help you with it, yet again, I'm not sure that's going to work. There might be other languages better suited for this than Java

Comment: One option might be to put your answer on the clipboard, where a user can ctrl + V to paste the number into Excel or Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using "Robot" to simulate keyboard press,
I post an example below is number button 1's acitonPerformed in my floating number keypad

```
 private void btn01ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    Boolean f = false;
    // for input numbers into jtextfield in  java applications
    Object source = evt.getSource();
    if (source instanceof JButton) {
        JButton btn = (JButton) source;
        try {


           
            String val = String.valueOf(btn.getText());


            Component comp = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner();
            if (comp instanceof JTextComponent) {
                JTextComponent tc = (JTextComponent) comp;
                tc.setText(tc.getText() + val);
                f = true;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
        }
    }
    
    // below for input number 1 into other programs
    if (!f) {
        Robot r;
        try {
            r = new Robot();
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
        } catch (AWTException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(calculator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }




}
```

[image: key in number from floating key pad to Excel]